# Pinescript Array saying index is out of bounds when I am checking the size first?

Tags: pine-script-v5

Pinescript array, checking to see if array size is minimal needed, yet it is display this error [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE7yx.png)

Here is the code I am refering:

```
if  confirmedTriangle and array.size(triangle_price)>4  and array.size(triangle_index)>4
    for i = 0 to 3
        //Slope
        xIndexDis   = array.get(triangle_index, 0) - array.get(triangle_index, 4)// : na
        yPriceDis   = array.get(triangle_price, 0) - array.get(triangle_price, 4)// : na
        xIndexDis2   = array.get(triangle_index, 3) - array.get(triangle_index, 1)// : na
        yPriceDis2   = array.get(triangle_price, 3) - array.get(triangle_price, 1)// : na
        
        m = yPriceDis / xIndexDis       //Gradient for bottom line
        m2 = yPriceDis2 / xIndexDis2    // Gradient for top line

        x1 = array.get(triangle_index, i)-testLength
        y1 = array.get(triangle_price, i)
        x2 = array.get(triangle_index, i+1)-testLength
        y2 = array.get(triangle_price, i+1)
        array.push(tri_array, line.new(x1,y1,x2,y2, color=color.white))
        
        xa1 = array.get(triangle_index,4)
        xa2 = array.get(triangle_index,0)
        xb1 = array.get(triangle_index,3)
        xb2 = array.get(triangle_index,1)
        
        ya1 = array.get(triangle_price,4)
        ya2 = array.get(triangle_price,0)
        yb1 = array.get(triangle_price,3)
        yb2 = array.get(triangle_price,1)
        
        label.new(bar_index, high+atr, text="Xa1 = " + str.tostring(xa1) + " / Ya1 = " + str.tostring(ya1) + "\n Xa2 = " + str.tostring(xa2) + " / Ya2 = " + str.tostring(ya2) + "\nXb1 = " + str.tostring(xb1) + " / Yb1 = " + str.tostring(yb1) + "\n Xb2 = " + str.tostring(xb2) + " / Yb2 = " + str.tostring(yb2))
```

I don't get any errors on sometimeframes but the majority do present the same error,

Answer (score 0):

Found the issues,
I assigned array.size(triangle_price) to a variable
e.g. arraySize = array.size(triangle_price)
In confirmedTriangle I was checking if arraySize>4, but the array size had been changed since that check

Simple fix was just to remove "arraySize = array.size(triangle_price)" and use array.size(triangle_price) in each check